# html is working perfectly without any errors on compiler but not in website

Tags: javascript, html, cpanel

I have tried it on 4 or 5 different compilers (apps & online compilers) and it works perfectly. But when i try to upload in on my website, part of it (script) becomes not working. I uploaded it on 2 different websites of mine and i got same result. I can't understand why, what is the difference between compilers and websites? Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What part of the script is failing? Post some code so we can understand the problem better

Comment: Never mind i solved it but i can't explain lol i just deleted some parts of it